# How to get the selected index of a RadioGroup in AlertDialog android

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I'm doing an app which change the background color depending of the button that is pressed but I'm facing a problem. What I want to do is to get the selected color in a RadioGroup which is on my AlertDialog,  I have tried many ways and I can't get it and I couldn't find a similar answer to this.

```
public void alertDialogColors()
{

    final View toDisplayInDialog = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.radiogroup, null);

    AlertDialog.Builder builder2 = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder2.setView(toDisplayInDialog);
    builder2.setMessage("Choose Startup Color");
    builder2.setPositiveButton("Set Startup Color", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            RadioGroup myRadioGroup = (RadioGroup)toDisplayInDialog.findViewById(R.id.RadioGroup);
            int radioGroupId = myRadioGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
            RadioButton myCheckedButton = (RadioButton)toDisplayInDialog.findViewById(radioGroupId);
            int index = myRadioGroup.indexOfChild(myCheckedButton);

            switch(index)
            {
                case 0:
                    saveColors(KEY_COLOR, Color.WHITE);
                    break;

                case 1: 
                    saveColors(KEY_COLOR, Color.BLACK);
                    break;

                case 2:
                    saveColors(KEY_COLOR, Color.RED);
                    break;

                case 3: 
                    saveColors(KEY_COLOR, Color.YELLOW);
                    break;

                case 4:
                    saveColors(KEY_COLOR, Color.GREEN);
                    break;

            }

        }
    })

    .setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    })
    .create()
    .show();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this..

```
    public void saveButtons(String temp, boolean bool)
{
    SharedPreferences.Editor ed = myPrefs.edit();
    ed.putBoolean(temp, bool);
    ed.commit();
}

//Alert Dialog Colors
public void alertDialogColors()
{

    final View toDisplayInDialog = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.radiogroup, null);
    final RadioGroup myRadioGroup = (RadioGroup)toDisplayInDialog.findViewById(R.id.RadioGroup);
    RadioButton checkRadioButton = (RadioButton) myRadioGroup.getChildAt(indexCheckRadioButton);
    checkRadioButton.setChecked(true);

    AlertDialog.Builder builder2 = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder2.setView(toDisplayInDialog);
    builder2.setMessage("Choose Startup Color");
    builder2.setPositiveButton("Set Startup Color", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            int radioGroupId = myRadioGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
            RadioButton myCheckedButton = (RadioButton)toDisplayInDialog.findViewById(radioGroupId);
            int index = myRadioGroup.indexOfChild(myCheckedButton);
            indexCheckRadioButton = index;

            switch(index)
            {
                case 0:
                    saveColors(KEY_COLOR, Color.WHITE);
                    saveRadioButton(KEY_RADIOBUTTON, indexCheckRadioButton);
                    break;

                case 1: 
                    saveColors(KEY_COLOR, Color.BLACK);
                    saveRadioButton(KEY_RADIOBUTTON, indexCheckRadioButton);
                    break;

                case 2:
                    saveColors(KEY_COLOR, Color.RED);
                    saveRadioButton(KEY_RADIOBUTTON, indexCheckRadioButton);
                    break;

                case 3: 
                    saveColors(KEY_COLOR, Color.YELLOW);
                    saveRadioButton(KEY_RADIOBUTTON, indexCheckRadioButton);
                    break;

                case 4:
                    saveColors(KEY_COLOR, Color.GREEN);
                    saveRadioButton(KEY_RADIOBUTTON, indexCheckRadioButton);
                    break;

            }
        }
    })

    .setNegativeButton("Cancel", null)
    .create()
    .show();
}


public void saveRadioButton(String temp3, int color2)
{
    SharedPreferences.Editor ed3 = myPrefs.edit();
    ed3.putInt(temp3, color2);
    ed3.commit();
}
```